# Using ArrayController with multiple models

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a `Route` which loads multiple models:

```
App.AppRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
          models1: this.store.find('model1'),
          models2: this.store.find('model2'),
          models3: this.store.find('model3'),
      })
  }
});
```

I want to extend the `ArrayController` for this page:

```
App.AppController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
```

And the error is thrown:

> Error: Assertion Failed: ArrayProxy expects an Array or Ember.ArrayProxy, but you    passed object

My question is how to write a controller which can handle multiple model objects.

Answer (score 2):

Really an array doesn't make since.  You have 3 different arrays.

So it would be an object controller, and you can access each item as an array in the application template or wherever it's appropriate.

```
App.AppController = Ember.ObjectController.extend();
```